# Run Web-Service and Client on two computers

Tags: c#, web-services, localhost

I have to run my Web-Service project on two computers. I have created very simple project with tutorial helps, but it working only on localhost. Next thing I have to do is create a local network, where on first computer I will run web-server and second will be a client.
Do you have some ideas how to do this?
I'm new in C# and WS technology.

Comment: Are both machines connecting to a single domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Virtual Machine on your Computer to simulate a small local network.
The server socket must be bind to your network ip address or just 0.0.0.0, so that it is reachable from everywhere.
It would help to post some code here, to show what you already have done.